# Modify dynamically added content

Tags: dynamic, jquery

I have used the search.. and tried many things.. but I just dont get it to work. Here is what I do:

On change of a select, I request some Data, in JSON-Format.
After that, I call a function:

```
  if (result.events) {
    $('#filter_result').trigger('put_result', result);
  }
```

In put_results() I build the HTML:

```
  $('#filter_result').bind('put_result', function (e, data) {
    html = '<h1 class="header_dates">Termine</h1>';
    // and some more
    $(this).html(html).stop(true, true).stop(true, true).slideDown();
  }
```

What I want to do now, is modify part of the #filter_result HTML. I want to look in one  that was build, and get the value.

The HTML markup that is inserted looks like this:

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Großraum</th>
          <th>Thema</th>
          <th>Termin</th>
          <th>Anmeldung</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="last">
          <td class="key_0">Berlin</td>
          <td class="key_1">273</td>
          <td class="key_2">27.04.2012</td>
          <td class="key_4"><a href="link/273.html" class="btn_jetzt_anmelden partnerallowed">Jetzt anmelden</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

To do that, I have written a function that gets called just after the "trigger" line. I thought about something like:

```
function unsetlink(){
    if(Date.parse($('.key_2').live().HTML()).equals(Date.today().add(2).days())) {
        alert('false');
    }
    else {
        alert('true');
    }
}
```

I use date.js for date comparison. The functions logic is working, thats not the problem. Its just that I think i'm using live at the wrong place or something like that. I just cant find an answer.. Anything that could help is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: `$('.key_2').live().HTML()` -> What does this means? or What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I was trying out anything to get the value inside key_2 .. this can be wrong... It was just an idea.. :)

Comment: It might be important to note that you appear to be using date.js from http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: I think we need to see the rendered markup for `.key_2` in order to answer this.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: <table><thead><tr><th>Großraum</th><th>Thema</th><th>Termin</th><th>Anmeldung</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="last"><td class="key_0">Berlin</td><td class="key_1">273</td><td class="key_2">27.04.2012</td><td class="key_4"><a href=273.html" class="btn_jetzt_anmelden partnerallowed">register</a></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: @ChristianRomeni - Just noticed, and I do not know for sure why, but in the comment markup the `href` does not have properly paired quotes whereas the one in your example above has it properly quoted - my assumption is that it is a simple copy/paste issue and NOT in your original code that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your updates, and making the assumption that the content exists when you call it, the function should be:

```
function unsetlink() {
    if (Date.parse($('.key_2').text()).equals(Date.today().add(2).days())) {
        alert('false');
    } else {
        alert('true');
    }
}
```

Here is a hacked together test for the function: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/86mDa/

EDIT2: Here is an example of processing multiple injected content groups: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/86mDa/3/

Here is the code in that example:

```
function unsetlink(daysadvance) {
    $('.key_2').each(function() {
        if (Date.parse($(this).text()).equals(Date.today().add(daysadvance).days())) {
            $(this).addClass('showFalse');
            $('#me').text($(this).text());//this is just to show what we are processing currnetly
            alert('false');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('showTrue');
            alert('true');
        }
    })
}
$('#me').after('<table><thead><tr><th>Großraum</th><th>Thema</th><th>Termin</th><th>Anmeldung</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="last"><td class="key_0">Berlin</td><td class="key_1">273</td><td class="key_2">27.04.2012</td><td class="key_4"><a href="273.html" class="btn_jetzt_anmelden partnerallowed">register</a></td></tr><tr class="last"><td class="key_0">Berlin</td><td class="key_1">273</td><td class="key_2">28.04.2012</td><td class="key_4"><a href="273.html" class="btn_jetzt_anmelden partnerallowed">register</a></td></tr></tbody></table>');
var daysadvance = 3;
unsetlink(daysadvance);
```

Comment: This seems to work, I'll give you a final feedback in appr. 9 hours.

Comment: This works for one result, but if I have two .key_2 td's it stops working.

Comment: Yes, with more than one, you are going to have to process them as an array of object - such as with jQuery `.each()`. I can put an update in that will illustrate that, although I am starting to think we may need more contextual markup - will try without that first.

Comment: I have finished the code, and all is working... Each was the solution, I found it a few minutes later... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Today I noticed another problem... After the content is loaded, and I successfully modify it (    $(this).next('.key_4').html('<a href="./files/warnung.png" class="warnung">ERROR</a>');) I have to klick TWICE on the link to open the fancybox, that is initialised like this: 
  $('a.warnung').live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).fancybox();
    return false;
  });
Any Idea?

Comment: As this seems to be something different, I would suggest you gather your code, and create another question with the markup and code in that new question including the fancybox reference and any other information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to access some elements that will be added to the DOM inside the custom event `put_result`.

If that is the case, then I suggest you write a callback function to the `put_result` event which will be called after you append to DOM. See below,

```
$('#filter_result').bind('put_result', function (e, data, callback) {
    html = '<h1 class="header_dates">Termine</h1>';
    // and some more
    $(this).html(html).stop(true, true).slideDown(); //removed one .stop(true, true)

    callback(); //invoke the callback at the end or when needed accordingly
});
```

And in the trigger,

```
//unsetlink is your callback function - Change it to an inner function
//if you want to do more and then call unsetlink at the end.
$('#filter_result').trigger('put_result', [result, unsetlink]);
```

And change your `unsetlink` function as

```
function unsetlink(){
    if(Date.parse($('.key_2').text()).equals(Date.today().add(2).days())) {
        alert('false');
    } else {
        alert('true');
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, the function unsertlink() is called, but nothing happens...

 function unsetlink(){
  alert('unset');
  if(Date.parse($('.key_2').HTML()).equals(Date.today().add(2).days()) || Date.parse($('.key_2').live().HTML()).equals(Date.today().add(1).days())) {
   link = false;
   alert('false');
  }
  else {
   link = true;
   alert('true');
  }
 }

I get the alert "unset", but nothing after that.

Comment: @ChristianRomeni Its either `$('.key_2').html()` or `$('.key_2').text()` not `$('.key_2').HTML()`